How to handle Aamarpay API response for payment status in Django REST framework?
I'm using Django REST Framework and integrating the Aamarpay payment gateway via their API. After a transaction is processed, I want to check and verify the payment status to update the order in my database. However, I’m unsure about the correct way to handle the Aamarpay API response and verify if the payment was successful.
